# retrieve data from web service and display in mvc 4 View

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, wsdl, soap-client

for my project I want to retrieve data from WSDL service. I have added service reference and made service object. above WSDL service contains method called getAvailableList(). that method passed int Array. below is my web service and Action method.

```
WebReference.GMeService IM = new WebReference.GMeService();
 public ActionResult Ataxi()
    {
        var alist = IM.getAvailableList();
        return View(alist);
    }
```

I want to check int type items passed by getAvailable() method is equal to employee model id or not. And If item passed by getAvailableList() method equals to is in employee model, that should display View.
below is Ataxi View.

```
@model List<WEB1.Models.employee>
@foreach(var item in Model){
@if (item.SE_ID != null)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SE_ID)
}
}
```

I have tried above code and get error message like The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WEB1.Models.employee]'.

can somebody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You stated yourself that `IM.getAvailableList()` returns an int array, but in the view that the model is expecting is `List<WEB1.Models.employee>`.  You're telling the view to expect one thing and then passing in another.

Comment: how do I correct it?I'm new to this technology.

Comment: change in view model List<WEB1.Models.employee> to model WEB1.Models.employee and dont display in foreach. you are not sending list from controller